# Login with Azure Credentials for windows Kivy-Python app

Tags: python, windows, azure-active-directory, kivy, kivy-language

I need to create a windows app where users can log in to the app using windows azure credentials and then the app calls the API after the user has successfully logged in. I am extremely new to python and so far all the solution I found was related to the python web app. I have seen similar functionality in google cloud SDK login but I have no idea how to implement it using Kivy-Python on my own. Is there any way to achieve this? If so please guide me on how to do it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you full solution, but there is the latest python MSAL library ready for your example, as docs said:

The Microsoft Authentication Library for Python enables applications to integrate with the Microsoft identity platform. It allows you to sign in users or apps with Microsoft identities (Azure AD, Microsoft Accounts and Azure AD B2C accounts) and obtain tokens to call Microsoft APIs such as Microsoft Graph or your own APIs registered with the Microsoft identity platform. It is built using industry standard OAuth2 and OpenID Connect protocols

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

It works for Windows: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Microsoft-Authentication-Client-Libraries